# Own Wordpress plugin, problems with a MySQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

WordPress tells me that I have an syntax error on Description:

> [30-Jul-2019 16:50:51 UTC] WordPress-Datenbank-Fehler You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''\do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, activate_shn_product, require_once('/plugins/shn-product/includes/class-shn-product-activator.php'), Shn_Product_Activator->__construct, Shn_Product_Activator->shn_store_products, dbDelta

I already tried it with `mysqli_real_escape` but it doesn't change anything.

```
{
    "id": 47,
    "name": "Brutal Anadrol 90caps",
    "purchasePrice": "",
    "price": "",
    "specialPercent": "0.00",
    "specialPercentFMS": "0.00",
    "pricePercentSHNStudio": "36.07",
    "pricePercentSHNDealer": "15.28",
    "franchisePercent": "4.50",
    "depositPrice": "0.00",
    "status": true,
    "statusFMS": true,
    "statusSHN": true,
    "hasGermanLabel": true,
    "needsLabel": true,
    "stockIsEditableByShopManager": false,
    "fsk18": true,
    "taxClass": 2,
    "description": "\u003Cp style=\u0022text-align: justify;\u0022\u003EEin gro\u00dfartiger TST-Booster ist der \r\nAufgabe gewachsen. Er funktioniert, wie erwartet, innerhalb der \r\nerlaubten Grenzen der Herstellung von Nahrungsmittelerg\u00e4nzungen. Es gibt\r\n nur ein Problem: die Ber\u00fccksichtigung von Regeln und Standards, denen \r\nandere folgen.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\u003Cp style=\u0022text-align: justify;\u0022\u003EBrutal Anadrol ist anders. Beim \r\nZusammenstellen haben wir nicht an Legalit\u00e4t gedacht, sondern an \r\nEffektivit\u00e4t und haben deshalb etwas kreiert, was so ist wie nichts \r\nanderes je zuvor.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\u003Cp style=\u0022text-align: justify;\u0022\u003ESei kein Mitl\u00e4ufer.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\u003Cp style=\u0022text-align: justify;\u0022\u003EVerwende Brutal Anadrol, bevor es verboten wird!\u003C\/p\u003E\u003Ch3\u003E\u003Cspan style=\u0022font-size: 18px;\u0022\u003EZutaten\u003C\/span\u003E\u003C\/h3\u003E\r\n\t\t\u003Cp\u003ETribulus terrestris-Frucht-Extrakt 19,1%, CreaBASE (gepufferte \r\nKreatin-Monohydrat) 19,1%, Camellia sinensis-Blatt-Extrakt, Kapselh\u00fclle \r\n[Gelatine, gereinigtes Wasser, Farbstoffe (Titandioxid, Brillantblau \r\nFCF, Ponceau 4R*)], Arginin Hydrochlorid 12,5%, \r\nCalcium-alpha-Ketoglutarat 11%, Niacin (Nicotinamid), Serenoa \r\nrepens-Frucht-Extrakt 1,9%, Silybum marianum-Samen-Extrakt, Panax \r\nginseng-Wurzel-Extrakt, Lepidium meyenii Pulver, Trennmittel \r\n(Magnesiumstearat, Siliciumdioxid), Bacopa monnieri Pulver, Coenzym Q10.\u003C\/p\u003E\u003Cp\u003E\u003Cbr\u003E\u003C\/p\u003E",
    "weight": "0.11",
    "width": 62,
    "height": 115,
    "depth": 62,
    "numberOfSales": 308,
    "packagingUnit": null,
    "restockDate": null,
    "createDate": {
        "date": "2015-10-17 23:45:25.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe\/Berlin"
    },
    "categorieId": 6,
    "childProductId": null,
    "manufacturerId": 4,
    "dosageFormId": 4,
    "productVariationId": null
}
```

And this is the Code which i use for it

foreach ($products as $product){

```
     $description = esc_sql( addslashes($product->description));
    $description = str_replace(array("\\r", "\\n", "\\t"), " ", $description);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $this->cache_table_name . " (`id`, `name`, `description` , `purchase_price`, `price`, `weight`, `width`, `height`, `depth`) 
    VALUES
        ('" .
           $product->id . "', '" .
           $product->name . "', '"  .
           $description . "', '" .
           $product->purchasePrice . "', '" .
           $product->price . "', '" .
           $product->weight . "', '" .
           $product->width . "', '" .
           $product->height . "', '" .
           $product->depth . "');";
    dbDelta($sql);

}
```

This is my Code where he is Inserting

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Your error seems to tell us that you're passing in php code as if it were sql. But as aynber suggests, we cannot tell you what goes wrong or how to fix it without seeing some of the code.

Comment: Added my code, i dont find something whats wrong

Comment: Is it possible for you to switch to bound parameters? I appreciate you're trying to escape values here, but I would not be inclined to trust that.

Answer (score 0):

1- Are you sure that you can insert data with `dbDelta` in Wordpress?

## Function Reference/dbDelta

```
The dbDelta function looks at the current table structure, compares it to the desired table structure passed to the function, and either adds or modifies the table. It is often used in plugins to create (if the table doesn't exist) or update the table structure. Read more about creating tables in WordPress here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins.

In order for the function to work correctly, the SQL statement must use the following criteria:

1. You have to put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.

2. You have to have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the definition of your primary key.

3. You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.
```

Also, you must include `upgrade.php` before `dbDelta()`  ;

```
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);
```

2- Usually, I insert data to MySql with below code.

```
$wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            ...
            ...
            ...
        ) 
    );
```

Comment: I will try it with wpdb insert but with dbdelta it works also, he does insert some data but with many he has Problems :/